# Modulating a MatLab signal

Tags: matlab, signals, modulation

I'm trying to modulate a signal in MatLab by multiplying some signal with a carrier signal. The carrier signal is `cos(2*pi*fc*t)` and this is my code so far

```
for t = 1:length(input);  
      m(t) = (Ac + input(t)).*cos(2*pi.*fc.*t);
end
xam = m;
```

input, Ac and fc are parameters that need to be entered when using the function. When I run this code with any input signal (I've been using `cos(t)` with `t = 0:0.001:10`) the output is always the same signal. However if I use ./ instead of .* in front of the fc, the output is modulated. Why does using .*fc instead of ./fc not work?

Comment: What is the `fc` value that is giving you trouble? And how do you declare m before the loop? `m = zeros(1, length(input))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you can vectorize your equation like so:

```
t = 0:0.001:10;
input = cos(t);
xam = (Ac + input).*cos(2*pi*fc*(1:length(t)));
```

I suspect that the reason you are seeing the exact same output curve each time is that your `fc` value is an integer. If `fc` is an integer, `cos(2*pi*fc*t)` evaluates to 1 for all integer values of `t`, leaving the input signal unchanged after modulation. When you use `1/fc` you get a non-integral value and the output is modulated.

I believe what you want to do is the following:

```
t = 0:0.001:10; % Time in seconds
f = 1; % Frequency of input signal in rad/s
fc = 3; % Frequency of carrier wave in rad/s
input = cos(2*pi*f*t); % Input signal
xam = (Ac + input).*cos(2*pi*fc*t); % Amplitude modulated signal
```

The comments show the meaning of each argument. If you only wanted to pass the sampling rate `fs` into your function, the solution would look like this:

```
N = 1001;
fs = 1000;
t = (0:1:N)*(1/fs);
f = 1;
fc = 3;
input = cos(2*pi*f*t);
```

And your function would look like so:

```
function xam = modulate(input, fs, fc, Ac) 
    t = (0:1:length(input))*(1/fs);
    xam = (Ac + input).*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
```

Comment: Cause I'm trying to keep the function general, how can I use the size function to get t equal to the right array? Like let's say an input of sin(x) is given and x = 0:0.01:20. How would I get t to = 0:0.01:20?

Comment: What do you mean by the "write array"? My edit offers a way to work around your problem. Make sure you understand the meaning of the `fc` and `t` parameters.

Comment: Sorry, rushed the response, I edited my above comment.

Comment: See my latest edit for an explanation of each value. The function should take in both the input signal and a `t` vector to describe the time domain of the signal. This is as general as you can get.

Comment: I get what each line does but I'm wondering how to set t based on the input array. If I want to modulate sin(x) but I don't know the dimensions of x then using t = 0:0.001:10 wouldn't work cause the dimensions could be different. So how would I set t based on whatever the input is? The input is not always going to be cos(2*pi*t). Is there no way to get t without asking for it as an input to the function?

Comment: It is impossible to set `t` based on the input array alone, you either need to pass in the `t`, or pass in the sampling rate `fs` as a scalar value.

Comment: How would you do it using fs?